# How do I get Korean (Hangul) characters to typeset in LaTeX ?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, languages, cjk

I've been unable to find a concise answer anywhere else on the web. Since its only a few words, albeit crucial ones, that are in Korean I don't want to have to muck around with HLaTex or deviate from pdfLaTeX that I'm using at the moment.

Answer (score 29):

Personally, I had a lot of trouble trying to get the CJK package to work. So I went on the KTUG website and found that they use the package kotex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kotex}
\begin{document}
안녕하세요!
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

The good part about this was I was able to simply copy and paste hangul from websites into the LaTeX document and it worked fine. I only wanted a few words (my name) as well, so this option might be quicker and easier.

Comment: I was having _Package inputenc Error: Unicode character   (U+FFFD) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX_  error. Your answer solved it and saved my time.

Comment: Works for Mandarin and Japanese too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [CJK](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/CJK) package. A little example (taken from [CJKutf8.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/languages/chinese/CJK/cjk-4.8.2/examples/CJKutf8.tex)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{mj}

  이 FAQ 은 자주 반복되는 질문과 그에 대한 대답을 간단명료한 양식으로
  모아 엮어졌습니다.

\end{CJK}

This FAQ list was made to summarize some frequently asked questions
and their answers in a convenient form.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there are so many different articles around about getting korean to work easily in latex, this worked extremely well and very easily

Comment: @Gonzalo  When I tried to run the code in my machine. It is giving following error     ! Font C70/mj/m/n/10/c7=uwmjc7 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fo
und.'. Can you suggest me on this. Thanking on advance

Comment: @Ansu the font is missing in your system. Install it using the package manager of your LaTeX system.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina One more question What is the name of the package for the korean fonts?

Comment: @Ansu the package is `CJKutf8`; your system seems to be missing some metric font file `uwmjc7.tfm`

Comment: Is this possible using XeLaTex? When I compile the above code, no errors occur, but I just get blank spaces where the Korean text should be.

Comment: Isn't there a way to write Korean without having to put special tags around it? This is better than the error I got before but still pretty annoying... Edit: @MoogleLogic post below answers the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Found a simpler way.

I had to input only a file name in Korean script (as per computer font name its "Gulim") while rest of the document is in English. Initially I could not get it compiled due to the font not set

What I did was to include as below under the input preamble (you can add the required fonts too in the same way) and yeah my job was done.

```
\usepackage{xeCJK}  
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}  
\setCJKsansfont{SimHei}  
\setCJKmonofont{FangSong}  
\setCJKmainfont{Gulim}
```

Hope it helps!! Cheers!

Comment: Why are you defining two `\setCJKmainfont` commands? Also, you should mention that this solution requires `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Will answer works for me.

If you want to install kotex package, you can use this repository URL in Tex Live Manager 2013.

http://ftp.ktug.org/KTUG/texlive/2013/

If you use other version, such as 2011, you can just change the number in URL.

Manual of this answer is written in below page (But written in Korean).

http://faq.ktug.org/faq/ko.TeX/instpack