# Korean font inside style file

Tags: fonts, cjk

I'm starting in my thesis which, while written primarily in English, needs a few lines of Korean font for things like professor names. Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17143/how-do-i-get-korean-hangul-characters-to-typeset-in-latex) I figured out how to typeset Korean characters which works well in the main body of the text.

However, when I try to pass Korean in as the argument to one of the macros defined in the style file the generated output is gibberish. What do I have to do to be able to pass Korean in as an argument?

Here are the commands I'm using. `\makesigpageB` is a macro defined in the style file and produces gibberish (ìİťëęĎ) for the 5th name. I also tried moving the `\inKorean` command inside the style file but that didn't help. I even tried hardcoding some Korean in the style file (after including the same packages) but still got the same gibberish.

The later call to `\inKorean`, though, produces the correct output.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJK}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{utepcsthesis} % thesis style file

\newenvironment{Korean}{%
  \CJKfamily{mj}}{}
\newcommand{\inKorean}[1]{\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{}\begin{Korean}#1\end{Korean}\end{CJK}}

\begin{document}

\makesigpageB{Chair, Prof 1}{Prof 2}{Prof 3}{Prof 4}{\inKorean{교수님 5}}

\inKorean{본문}

\end{document}
```

In the sytle file ...

```
\newcommand{\makesigpageB}[5]{
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
% title
{\large\bf\@title}\\[0.4in]
% author
{\large\@author}\\[0.4in]
% department
{\large\@deptnm}
\end{center}
\vfill
\hspace{3.5in}APPROVED:\\[0.1in]

\noindent
\hspace{3.5in}\underline{\hspace{2.9in}}

\noindent
\hspace{3.5in}#1\\[0.05in]

\noindent
\hspace{3.5in}\underline{\hspace{2.9in}}

\noindent
\hspace{3.5in}#2\\[0.05in]

\noindent
\hspace{3.5in}\underline{\hspace{2.9in}}

\noindent
\hspace{3.5in}#3\\[0.05in]

\noindent
\hspace{3.5in}\underline{\hspace{2.9in}}

\noindent
\hspace{3.5in}#4\\[0.05in]

\noindent
\hspace{3.5in}\underline{\hspace{2.9in}}

\noindent
\hspace{3.5in}#5 %
\noindent

\newpage}
```

Comment: Do you have `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in your document?

Comment: No, but would that explain why it works in one place (the body) and not the other (in the .sty file)?

Comment: If I add it, I get Korean characters under the last signature line.

Comment: Sure enough, that worked. Thanks! If you add it as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{}` requires you to have

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

in your preamble. Of course the document must be UTF-8 encoded.

As Leo Liu (an expert in this field) says, it's probably even better to say

```
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
```

so the cooperation between `CJK` and `inputenc` will be ensured.

Comment: One should use `CJKutf8` package instead of `CJK` + `inputenc`. And it is always preferred to use `CJK` environment globally.

Comment: @LeoLiu What's the difference?

Comment: @egeg: `CJKutf8` package has some patches for `inputenc` to make sure that the two package don't conflict. Both `inputenc` and `CJK` manipulate catcodes of characters in the range of 0x80--0xFF.

Comment: `CJK` environment is safer to be used globally. There may be some subtle problems. e.g. It is often necessary (described in the document of `CJK` pkg) to use a `\clearpage` before `\end{CJK}` to prevent a bug that cannot be repaired.