# Korean Characters Not Working

Tags: languages, cjk

I set up hlatex (the package for compiling in Korean) but when I build the file, I end up getting ?? instead of 안녕. How do you fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hangul}
\begin{document}
testing 안녕
\end{document}
```

No errors come up. The word "testing" comes up, but "안녕" does not.

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE (minimum working example) that generates the problem you're trying to solve. As it stands, your posting doesn't really provide sufficient information to allow a decent diagnosis of what may be going on.

Comment: Sorry, but no `hangul.sty` package is on CTAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [CJK](http://ctan.org/pkg/cjk) bundle.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{mj}
``하나님이 세상을 이처럼 사랑하사 독생자를 주셨으니 이는 그를 믿는 자마다 멸망하지 않고 영샘을 얻게 하려 하심이라.'' - 요한복음 3:16
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

-- Reponse due to *Thorsten* (localghost on AoPS).

Comment: Maybe try @MoogleLogic answer from another thread : http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144607/128104 This worked great for me and I don't need to surround every piece of Korean text with a tag soup.

Answer (score 3):

I'm probably the wrong person to anwser, because I have no experience in Korean or CJK usage in latex, but if you "only" want to typeset Korean and (maybe) latin texts, I would suggest to use lualatex (or xelatex). The benefit is that those latex engines are build to use the UTF-8 encoding without any hacks and they support OTF fonts. So you can use any system font you have to typeset your document. Here is a small example:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Batang}
\setsansfont{Dotum}

\begin{document}
testing 안녕
{\sffamily testing 안녕}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I use the fonts Batang and Dotum shipped with Windows, but you can take any other that have Korean characters support. You probably know some of them. If you do not like the Latin letters you can also define commands to switch to the desired font:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Batang}
% or 
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\newfontfamily\dotum{Dotum}
\newfontfamily\batang{Batang}

\begin{document}
testing \batang 안녕
{\sffamily testing \dotum 안녕}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have predominantly Korean text you can of course define font commands for the latin text and use the Korean font as default. I hope I could give you a starting point.