Latex symbols korean make pdf using GitHub Actions
I'm using latex-action to build from code written in latex into a pdf using GitHub Actions.
The problem is that I'm having trouble with the Korean language.
Can you give me a hand?
Korean.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\title{Getting started}
\author{Korean}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

ㄱㄴㄷㄹ


안녕하세요

\end{document}

name: Build PDF from LaTeX Korean
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Set up Git repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Compile LaTeX document
      uses: xu-cheng/latex-action@v3
      with:
        root_file: ./latex/Korean.tex

    - name: Upload PDF artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: output
        path: '*.pdf'  # Update with the path to your PDF file

Error:
./latex/Korean.tex:14: Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undef
ined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `latin1'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.14 �
       �ㄴㄷㄹ
./latex/Korean.tex:14:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on Korean.log.
Latexmk: Sometimes, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
Latexmk: Getting log file 'Korean.log'
  to try to force complete processing.
  But normally, you will need to correct the file(s) that caused the
  error, and then rerun latexmk.
  In some cases, it is best to clean out generated files before rerunning
  latexmk after you've corrected the files.
Latexmk: Examining 'Korean.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'Korean.log'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'Korean.log' and/or above output for details


latin1 is really the wrong encoding for korean. Why don't you use utf8? And why don't you use an unicode engine like lualatex?

why would you specify you are using an 8 bit legacy encoding for latin script  if using utf-8 encoded Korean?  Use lualatex and unicode fonts

use lualatex not pdflatex and see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17143/1090
